# What is the English term for "dousing yourself with cold water to build immunity"

Tags: translation

In russian, the word "обливаться" can be colloquially used to describe a specific recurring  **activity where you pour a container of cold water on a person with the goal of building up that person's immunity**.

I there an equivalent English idiom/short expression for such an activity?

Comment: Immunity to what?

Comment: @StoneyB - overall boost to immune system. Random examples mentioning this: [\[1\]](http://www.news.com.au/travel/news/siberian-kids-believe-pouring-a-bucket-of-cold-water-in-icy-cold-temperatures-keeps-them-healthy/story-e6frfq80-1226522205905), [\[2\]](http://undergroundhealthreporter.com/health-benefits-of-cold-water-therapy#axzz2XFnYa9yf)

Comment: @StoneyB - in case you're skeptical about purpurted benefits of the activity, we have a [Stack Exchange site for that](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/) :)  The point is, it's a very common activity and term in Russian language, and I want to know if there's a concise way to refer to it in English that most Americans would understand what I'm talking about.

Comment: I would be very surprised if there were an English term for an activity which is not (to the best of my knowledge) practised among English speakers -- and which, it appears from your link, only began to be practised in Russia eighteen years ago.

Comment: @StoneyB - I didn't read the link in detail; but the practice began in Russia at LEAST ~100 years ago (my 4th generation ancestors were aware of it), and I wouldn't be surprised if it began closer to 1000.

Comment: @StoneyB - It's a fair point that the term can plausibly be missing, but the practice was known to Native Americans as well as circa-1900 Eastern European immigrants, so I would **not** be surprised if there's some nativeamerican/yiddish/russian/polish/german-derived word for it. But I don't hang out on fitness/natural health blogs so I don't know the lingo.

Comment: If you find you need to invent a term, you might use one drawn from blacksmithing: *quenching*, plunging heated steel into water to cool it abruptly, hardens the metal.

Comment: @StoneyB - interestingly, in russian, "обливаться" is part of an overall natural health approach referred to as "закалка". Guess what is the [second meaning](http://translate.google.com/#auto/en/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0) of that word? You got it, metallurgical quenching :)

Comment: I've never heard of the practice, so I don't know of a word for it. My guess is that, if there is a word for this in English, it is either a word that very few English speakers would be familiar with, or it is a word with a much more common and familiar meaning. Either way, I doubt anybody would know what you were talking about if you used that word to mean this.

Comment: I thought FumbleFingers' answer was good, and I was also surprised the OP wanted a word specifically for **toughening up via pouring cold water over a person**, not in general.  I voted to close, since I don't think there is a useful answer to the question.

Comment: What @snailboat said (well, I *would* say that, wouldn't I? :). For most learners, the relevant things to pick up on are (a) - Anglophones are much more likely to speak of "toughening up", rather than "gaining immunity" in *any* such contexts, and (b) - we don't usually think of cold showers as a way to "toughen up". In which context, note our common idiomatic expression [pour cold water on](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pour+cold+water+on) - *to discourage doing something; to reduce enthusiasm for something.*

Comment: @Daniel - frankly, if a word is found, I would not be very surprized if it's one from niche fitness/natural-living subculture vocabularies. But since that is the target audience I had in mind when I found myself seeking the English version, I'm quite fine with that.

Comment: Just had a discussion with a group of moderators, and the consensus is that if the answer to a question is "There is no answer to this" (or in this case, "There is no word for this in English"), the question doesn't deserve to be closed, but should be answered as such. So @FumbleFingers, if you don't mind, I invite you to undelete your answer and add that to the beginning, because the rest of the information in your answer is quite useful (and unless a word for this is invented on the spot, I think the OP is unlikely to receive an answer beyond "There is none"). What say you? :)

Comment: @WendiKidd: I've undeleted the answer because I think knowing about *toughen someone] up* would indeed be useful for many learners, and it's very closely related to what OP's asking for here. I don't yet know *what* I think about the fact that Too Localised is no longer available to us. Per my [answer on that topic in ELL Meta](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/3990/2637), I often seem to be out of step with the majority when I closevote as Too Localised. But even if there *is* an answer for DVK here, how relevant could it be to most learners?

Comment: @FumbleFingers From what I've gathered from the Community Team, the problem with Too Localized was that no one could agree on what it meant. One team member told me that Too Localized is much narrower in scope than people think it is, and almost never actually applies (as a percentage of questions closed as TL and questions the comm team thinks are TL). I'm hoping we will be able to work the 3 custom close options to our advantage, but we shall see.

Comment: Ah, and we seem to be starting a discussion now, so I'll also say that this is a *very* important subject to discuss but is better done on meta (or even meta.SO if you'd prefer to chime in there). On our meta we can talk about the 3 custom close reasons and how to use them, and how the close changes pertain to us. To petition the comm team and devs for other changes, meta.SO is probably the best place.

Comment: Seems to me there's a big difference between "this question cannot be answered" and "there is no such word". It's like software I sometimes run into where if you enter zero it gives you an error message saying "You must enter a number". I did enter a number: zero is a number. Likewise, sometimes blank or "not applicable" is a perfectly valid answer. I didn't refuse to answer the question: I answered "".

Comment: If there is anyone who knows if there is or is not an English word for this, it's Todd Becker. You can search his blog and/or contact him [here](http://gettingstronger.org/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay - here's another one that might turn up in "niche vocabularies", even if it's not used all that often...

> [cryotherapy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/cryotherapy?show=0&t=1372200856) *- the therapeutic use of cold*

...which could reasonably be combined with...

> [hydrotherapy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/hydrotherapy) *- the therapeutic use of water*

The above link has quite a lengthy definition, including *"alternating hot and cold water can stimulate the circulatory system and **improve the immune system**"*, so obviously *hydrotherapy* does actually cover OP's intended sense. But combining the two prefixes gives the more specific, and [semi-]credible...

> [**cryohydrotherapy**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22cryohydrotherapy%22&oq=%22cryohydrotherapy%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.40059340j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) *(no dictionary definition, obviously, but there are a few instances of it being used)*

Comment: My only concern is that "therapy" implies treatment from a medical condition as opposed to toughening one's immune system... otherwise I like this

Comment: @DVK: Actually, I hate to pour cold water on my own answer, but I've just gone to check that "About 171 results" link above. In fact, there are only 11 in total, of which 10 are all just duplicates of the same original. I think you'd be better off just using the well-established [Hydrotherapy](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Hydrotherapy), which as that "medical dictionary" entry says, covers use of *water (hot, **cold**, steam, or **ice**)* It also says *Alternating hot and cold water can stimulate the circulatory system and **improve the immune system**.*

Comment: You better incorporate that into the answer. I'm upvoting and accepting in advance

Answer (score 5):

I can't think of an idiomatic expression specifically evocative of a *repeated* activity leading to "immunity", but for the more general case (which may be a one-off, repeated, and/or prolonged activity), it's...

> [toughen someone (up)](http://oaadonline.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/toughen) *- to make someone stronger and more able to deal with difficult situations*

[Here, for example,](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22clamp%20down%20on%20free%20speech%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22toughened%20him%20up%22&oq=%22toughened%20him%20up%22&gs_l=serp.3...4560.9649.6.10001.9.9.0.0.0.0.69.467.9.9.0...0.0...1c.1.17.psy-ab.rMFsPJwVR1g&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48293060,d.d2k&fp=fe652708efb790b2&biw=1274&bih=930) are as few thousand instances in Google Books of *"toughened him up"*. If you look at a few, you'll see that although it's often used in contexts where the "toughening" refers to becoming more *physically* "robust" (stronger, better-toned muscles, etc.), it's also often used of "emotional" strength.

---

EDIT I deleted the above answer when OP clarified that he was looking for an English expression for *exactly* the meaning *being "toughened up" by **repeated** exposure to **cold water***. Obviously my answer doesn't get very close to that - as I said, it doesn't even imply *repeated*, let alone *cold water*.

I've now undeleted it because although there may not *be* an exact answer, this one is at least "relevant".

But I will just say that I think it's unlikely there will be a short English term evocative of cold water *and* "positive" effects such as acquiring immunity/becoming stronger. The reason I think it's unlikely is because any such usage would clash with a well-established idiom...

> [pour cold water on](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pour+cold+water+on) *- to discourage doing something; to reduce enthusiasm for something. (Alludes to cooling passion with cold water.)*

Comment: Sorry, I was specifically asking about toughening up **via pouring cold water over a person**, not in general. I don't have enough rep to downvote, but this does not answer the question at all.

Comment: @DVK: In that case I'll delete the answer, but I'm afraid I must say I think that if what you want is a translation for *toughening up by constant exposure to cold water*, you probably won't get one with any currency. It's not really a concept Anglophones relate to. Most references to the "toughening" effect of cold showers will probably be sarcastically/dismissively alluding to such practices in boarding schools, etc., where the audience/reader takes for granted that such practices produce "damaged/abused weaklings/victims", rather than strong healthy adults.

Comment: Provisionally accepting unless someone comes up with what I really want (a term common in niche vocabulary)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I think the English term for this activity will be "dousing" or "cold water dousing". Since this is not a common practice among Anglophones, you will probably have to give some more details when you write or talk about "dousing".

There is an article in Wikipedia about [dousing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dousing):

> Dousing is the practice of making something or someone wet by throwing liquid over them, e.g., by pouring water, generally cold, over oneself. A related practice is ice swimming. Some consider cold water dousing to be a form of asceticism.

There's also a list of countries in this article where this activity is practiced.

Comment: It's worth noting that the Wikipedia page is flagged as *does not cite any references or sources.* Using just the word *dousing* for any kind of hydrotherapy (cold or not) might be okay in specific contexts, but there's no relevant definition in either OED or the first few online dictionaries I've just looked at.

Answer (score 0):

This action could be described as ***conditioning***.